# error C2512: no appropriate default constructor available( no usage of default ctor in code)

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I've added a new member (Info  m_info) to a class called Tile, and want to initialize this new member with values as part of the Tile c'tor:

```
Tile::Tile(const image& myImage): m_image(myImage)
{       
    Info myInfo(1,0,VAL);
    m_info = myInfo;
}
```

this is Info  class:

```
class Info 
{
public: 

    Info(bool b1, bool b1, Car c1):
        b1(b1), b2(b2), c1(c1){}

    bool b1;
    bool b2;    
    Car c1;
};
```

I'm getting an error "error C2512: 'Info': no appropriate default constructor available". why? I don't see that a default c'tor is needed since I'm using the available c'tor with parameters.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that `m_info` is an `Info`, and as such must be initialized with parameters, which you haven't done here.

Comment: @Quentin I like your crystal-ball, you should hired it to work as an engineer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your `Tile(const image& myImage)` constructor, you initialize `m_info` using its default constructor (because it's not mentioned in `Tile`'s [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)). You then attempt to assign another (non-default) value to it.

To construct `m_info` correctly in the first place, you need

```
Tile::Tile(const image& myImage): m_image(myImage), m_info(1,0,VAL)
{       
}
```